# how does clearTimeout actually clears the timeout?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, event-loop

We save the `setTimeout` reference to be able to cancel it in the future. when we call `clearTimeout`

> will it immediately take it out of callback queue

or

> it will wait for the callback's turn and prevent it from running in that point in time

here is an example to clarify what do I mean;

```js
var a = setTimeout(()=>console.log("a"),1000);
var b = setTimeout(()=>console.log("b"),2000);

let isCancelled = false;

var c = setTimeout(()=>console.log("c"),2000);
var d = setTimeout(()=>{
  if(!isCancelled)
   console.log("d")
},2000);


clearTimeout( c ); // "c" won't show
isCancelled = true; // "d" won't show too
```

my intuition is that somehow (e.g. using a flag or something) it will wait for it's turn and prevent it from running, instead of immediately removing it from the queue since it's a queue, and searching an element require visiting all the elements till it finds the element which is `O(n)` in worst case, then removing the element, fixing pointers ( like double linklists ) and here we go, it removed immediately; But it is kinda inefficient since it should happen in the very core parts of language (event loop and other stuff) where time is scarce, while preventing from happening will be `O(1)` simply a `if` statement; but waiting for it's turn is kinda ugly, and not seems so smart;

---

**So** what do you guys think? which one? or maybe another approach to handle that?

thanks in advance;

Comment: Even a flag would need to be searched in a lookup structure to set it for that specific timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are valid implementation strategies. To find out which one is used, you would have to take a look at the source code of a particular implementation.

However, notice that even setting a flag on the data structure that holds the callback will require locating the right timer instance in the queue (by using the id that you pass to `clearTimeout`), so it might not be all that different in complexity. The only difference would be for memory management.

> since it's a queue, and searching an element require visiting all the elements till will find it which is `O(n)` in worst case

No, this depends on the data structure being used for the queue. Not all queues are implemented as linked lists. I would expect a much more efficient one.

Answer (score 0):

The specification [says](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-cleartimeout):

> The clearTimeout() and clearInterval() methods must clear the entry identified as handle from the list of active timers of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope object on which the method was invoked, if any, where handle is the argument passed to the method. (If handle does not identify an entry in the list of active timers of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope object on which the method was invoked, the method does nothing.)

So it is required that it be removed from the list.

Comment: That's the spec. It does not detail how this is actually implemented. An engine that would set a flag on the entry that identifies it as "was removed" would be conforming just as well.